# Why =. is not clearing the value of a variable in this case?

Tags: variable-definitions, variable, assignment

I am reading "Mathematics and Algorithms" as part of the Wolfram Tutorial series.

In "Values for symbols" section of the "Algebraic Calculations" chapter it is described that `=.` can be used to clear the contents of a variable.

I am struggling to be able to understand in which cases this is applicable.

For example, I have a notebook which I have been using for several tests and specifically I can not clear the value of x.

```
 In[] x
Out[] Removed[t]
 
 In[] x=.
Out[]

 In[] x
Out[] Removed[t]
```

Why `x` is not being cleared?

Comment: Please include relevant previous steps of your calculation that lead to this behavior. Example 1: If I `Quit[]` to get a fresh kernel, then use `x=t;Remove[t];x` I get `Removed[t]` like you, but then `x=.;x` gives `x` so the variable is cleared as expected. Example 2: If I `Quit[]` to get a fresh kernel, then use `x=t;x/:Unset[x]=Null;Remove[t];` then afterwards I see the same behavior as you. Example 2 is contrived, and just to illustrate that this behavior is possible, but I wonder what you did.

Comment: I do not know the relevant previous steps as I was reusing over and over the same notebook to follow a course. But it is good to know that with `Quit[]` I get a fresh kernel. If I ever identify what is generating this issue I will repost the path that lead to this behaviour. My expectation was that `=.` shall clear the symbol/variable always.

Comment: I almost always use `ClearAll[x]` instead.